# php file not accessible at client side when same file uploading on server through FTP

Tags: php, server, ftp, filezilla

I having bunch of `.php` files in local & server. Those all files using at client side (mobile app) as web services. But when those file/folder uploading on server via FTP after modified at that time some web service stopped working or misbehaving(returning HTML content in web service response) at client side because of file uploading process going on.

Sometime also facing this issue for single file too when my local network is slow and trying to upload file on server.

I having many live users and getting rarely this issue when file uploading from server side.

Having `AWS server` and `FileZilla` using for `FTP`.

Answer (score 1):

You face a typical problem of non-atomic operations. The solution is to make the operation atomic, that means, change all files at ones.

For this, you have all files in a directory, likely your `htdocs` directory. Next, you rename this directory to `htdocs1` and create a new directory `htdocs2`. And finally, you create a symbolic link `htdocs` to point to `htdocs1`.

Now, you can take all the time it takes to upload all new files to `htdocs2`. Once you are done, you change the symbolic link to point to `htdocs2` rather than `htdocs1`.

Finally, if you use some PHP accelerator, you might need to reload the webserver (or PHP-FPM) in case you face caching problems.

For the next update of your site, you do the same, just upload into `htdocs1` and then change the symbolic link back to it.

So in short:

```
mv htdocs htdocs1
mkdir htdocs2
ln -sTf htdocs1 htdocs
```

Just adjust the last command if you want to use the other directory.

In case you do not have shell access, you can also write a PHP script to do that for you, as PHP can also create symbolic links: http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php.